# Project Explorer - Project name different from actual folder name

Tags: eclipse

I have a folder "JDataCollectionDemo" and I change some variables example int temp from 40 to 50, and now I want to rename this folder as "JDataCollectionDemo50". When I open JDataCollectionDemo50 as a projectfrom File Systems, it will always shows up as "JDataCollectionDemo" under the project explorer.

How can I open it as a "JDataCollectionDemo50" folder under the project explorer? I might "JDataCollectionDemo100" but I always get one "JDataCollectionDemo" folder instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name you see in eclipse isn't the folder name. It is the name which is stored in the `.project` file (which depending on how you import the project may be the folder name initially).

You can either

- remove the project from eclipse rename the folder and the name in the `.project` file and then re-import the folder

or, easier

- select the project in eclipse and press F2 to rename it